# Nodejs App works locally but only two route is working on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, heroku, backend

Hello all first and foremost this issue may seem like a duplicate but it is not as I have gone through other SO post relating to mine but it still didnt help and hence the reason I am making another. Please I need help, I have a nodejs back-end that is working locally without any issue. I uploaded it to heroku and now only two routes is working. All other routes are not working.  I am able register, login and add new users.

This is for my add users routes that is working both locally and on heroku.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Router } from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import User from '../model/user';

import { authenticate } from '../middleware/authMiddleware';

export default({ config, db }) => {
let api = Router();

// '/v1/user/add' - Create
api.post('/add', authenticate, (req, res) => {
let newUser = new User();
newUser.username = req.body.username;
newUser.email = req.body.email;
newUser.phonenumber = req.body.phonenumber;
newUser.profilepicurlicUrl = req.body.profilepicurl;

newUser.save(err => {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err });
    return;
   }
    res.status(200).json(newUser);
  });
});
```

This is for my register user and login user that is working both locally and on heroku

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Router } from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import passport from 'passport';
import config from '../config';
import Account from '../model/account';
import UserDataExt from './extensions/userData-ext';
import async from 'async';
import crypto from 'crypto';

import { generateAccessToken, respond, authenticate } from '../middleware/authMiddleware';

var  nodeMailer = require('nodemailer');

export default ({ config, db }) => {
  let api = Router();

  // '/v1/account/register'
  api.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    UserDataExt.findUserByEmail(req.body.email, (err, userData) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(409).json({ message: `An error occured: ${err.message}`});
        return;
      } else if (userData) {
        res.status(300).json({ message: `Email ${req.body.email} is already registered`});
      }
      // else {
        Account.register(new Account({username: req.body.email}), req.body.password, function(err, account) {
          if(err) {
            res.status(500).json({ message: err });
            return;
          }

          console.log("Registering new account");
          passport.authenticate('local', { session: false })(req, res, () => {
              res.status(200).send('Successfully created new account');
          });
        });
      // }
    });
  });

  // '/v1/account/login'
  api.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
        UserDataExt.findUserByEmail(req.body.email, (err, userData) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(409).json({ message: `An error occured: ${err.message}`});
        return;
      } else {
                next();
            }
    });
    }, passport.authenticate('local', { session: false, scope: [] }), (err, req, res, next) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(401).json({ message: `Password is incorrect`});
      return;
        }
    }, generateAccessToken, respond);
```

This is for my category route that is not working on heroku, but is working locally

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Router } from 'express';
import Category from '../model/category';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import { authenticate } from '../middleware/authMiddleware';

export default({ config, db }) => {
  let api = Router();

  // /v1/category/add Create
  api.post('/add', authenticate, (req, res) => {

    let newCategory = new Category();
    newCategory.submittedById = req.body.submittedById;
    newCategory.categoryTitle = req.body.categoryTitle;
    newCategory.categoryDescription = req.body.categoryDescription;
    newCategory.recommended = req.body.recommended;


    newCategory.save(err => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).json({message: err});
        return;
      }
        res.status(200).json({message: 'Category saved successfully'});
    });
  });

  // /v1/category/ Read
  api.get('/', authenticate, (req, res) => {
    Category.find({}, (err, category) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).json({message: `An erro has occured ${err.message}`});
        return;
      }
        res.status(200).json(category);
    });
  });
```

This is my authenticate middleware code

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import expressJwt from 'express-jwt';

const TOKENTIME = 60*60*24*90;
const SECRET = "@@@@@@@";

let authenticate = expressJwt({ secret: SECRET });

let generateAccessToken = (req, res, next) => {
  req.token = req.token || {};
  req.token = jwt.sign ({
    id: req.user.id,
  }, SECRET, {
    expiresIn: TOKENTIME // 90 days
  });
  next();
}

let respond = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    user: req.user.username,
    token: req.token,
    id: req.user._id
  });
}

module.exports = {
  authenticate,
  generateAccessToken,
  respond
}
```

Comment: plz, show ur authenticate middleware code. Could it be the likely problem?

Comment: do you get any error codes for those requests?

Comment: @Muthukumar The only error i get in postman, is cannot post for post route and cannot get for get route

Comment: what is the response code in postman ? 401 or 404 ?

Comment: @Muthukumar I have added the authenticate middleware code, Please help review

Comment: @Muthukumar It is giving me 404 not found